# Is the 'find and replace' feature (found in the control panel settings screen) documented?

Tags: documentation

I see the feature, but would like to read about what and where it finds before replacing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a short description of what it does in the [2.0 release notes](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2524).

> Added a new Find and Replace tool in Settings, for **finding/replacing text within all Rich/Plain Text fields** (including ones in a Matrix field).

Comment: I'll mark this as correct, but it would be good to get a more full definition. What about custom fieldtypes that store content in the content table as plain text for example.

Comment: It says Rich/Plain Text fields, so if this information is correct then all other fields shouldn't be affected.

Comment: Yup... purely limited to Rich/Plain text fields.